# C# console application failing to accept input. Every time I input y or n in the console it closes the prograM

Tags: c#

```
        Console.WriteLine("Are you a male or female?m/f:");
        string taco = Console.ReadLine();


        string[] male = { "bob", "max", "marc", "sam", "tyler" }; //male array
        string[] female = { "samantha", "jen", "karen", "tracey", "clarissa" }; //female array


        Random rand = new Random();
        int index0 = rand.Next(male.Length);
        int index1 = rand.Next(female.Length);


        if (taco == "m")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Your name is: {male[index0]}");

        }
         else if (taco =="f")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Your name is: {female[index1]}");
        }
```

Not sure what is wrong? I've made quite a few user input codes and I'm honestly I'm straight up lost.

Comment: Maybe you're missing an additional `Console.Read()` at the end of your method. Do you want a loop?

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!!!

Comment: When a console application completes its logic, it terminates.  This application looks like it would accomplish that in about a milisecond after the initial user input.